# Discord.py bot reads message and if it encounters a particular word, copy and dm it to a particular user

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

I want my bot to read the messages and  if it encounters the word "John" in any of the messages, it should copy and dm the message to a specific user. Below is the code i've written but it's not doing anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import discord
from discord import Client
TOKEN = "insert token"
client = discord.Client()

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    MessageContent = message.content.lower()
    if "john" in MessageContent:
        user = client.get_user("insert user_id")
        await user.send(MessageContent)


bot.run(TOKEN, bot = False)
```

Comment: `bot` is not defined. How should this work?

Comment: I'm sorry but could you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: You won't receive support for self-bot in any modern version of discord.py. Also the user ID has to be an integer, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

rename `client = discord.Client()` to `bot = discord.Client()`